# Choice between NTLM or Kerberos

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

For an SharePoint 2010 intranet application how to decide which authentication type Kerberos or NTLM is suitable ?

In few cases Kerberos is mandatory but in NTLM is also suitable in few other cases. How to decide these authentication type? Can any one list out which type of application is suitable for each?

Comment: See this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13400/ntlm-vs-kerberos